# How to implement an enum class with multiple string attributes that might repeat?

Tags: java, oop, enums, hashmap, treemap

As a background refresher in OOP with Java I was attempting a design problem:

I have a bunch of names of people, along with attributes name, age and occupation. I want to implement a ListOfPersons enum class that's acting like a database with all of this info. The only problem is, a lot of the data in this list is duplicates, so for example, there might be two or three entries for age and occupation attributes.

```
Example:
Enum object one- 
Name: Joe
Age: 40
Age: 41
Occupation: Engineer
Occupation: Software Engineer
```

You can see for Joe, there are two age entries and two occupation entries.

```
Example 2:
Enum object two- 
Name: Judy
Age: 55
Age: 65
Occupation: Judge
```

In example 2, it's age that shows up twice.

The point is, there are a bunch of entries like this that have to implemented in an enum class. **What is an optimal way to set it up (my enum class of persons) with the intention of transferring to a TreeMap or HashMap (or is there a better data structure that can serve to act as a database for users to search up people)?**

The problem is, I am not sure how to take into account these random duplicate entries making it hard to put into a data structure later.

```
public enum ListOfPersons{
Joe("Joe", 40, 41, "Engineer", "Software Engineer"), Judy("Judy", 55, 65, 
"Judge")...etc.
//methods 
}
```

Comment: Do you want a list of Enums?

Comment: Why are there duplicated age entries?

Comment: If you know all the names from the beginning an enum could work, if the names are not known and they will be found out at runtime then better suited for the use case would be a `Map` with names as keys and as values an object with 3 `List` properties (one for age, one for job title and one for qualification)

Comment: @ValentinCarnu the objects will be searched with their names by the user.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the use case (some more details could help), what I understand is that you try to implement an application where the users can search by name and as a result they will see the ages of the people with the name they searched for. And the solution should be implemented using Enums

Comment: @ValentinCarnu yes, only caveat is there are duplicate entries associated with age and occupation attributes. User should be able to search name and specify an attribute (so Joe age should return both Joe's name and his 2 age entries from the data structure I load Joe's info from the enum class).

Comment: Is the association between the age and the occupation important. Something like _Joe of 33 of age is an Engineer_ and _Joe of 35 of age is a Software Engineer_?

Comment: @ValentinCarnu it doesn't have to be fancy, you could search "Joe age" and it could output :"Joe, age:33, age:35". No the association is not important. The emphasis is on uploading the data into an enum class that we then use a data structure to retrieve said data

Answer (score 1):

`enum` doesn't seem to be appropriate in your case.  A simpler approach would be to have a Person class (with fields you need), then override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods to include name as the unique identifier (I assume name is unique because you have attempted to put it as the name in your enum example).  Then you create a list of Person instances using `ArrayList`.

To have it process later in a data structure like `Map` (person name as key, person object as value), you can do:

```
Map<String, Person> personsMap = persons.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity());
```

Then to retrieve:  `personsMap.get("Joe")` to give you the Person instance

Comment: I agree it's more of a project spec thing to start with enum. I guess the idea is to practice loading data into data structures from various sources. that's why i'm trying to design my enum class right so the data structure loading goes well. Can you elaborate on the arraylist person instances?

Comment: ArrayList of person instances would be: arrayList.add (new Person("Joe", 40, 41, "Engineer", "Software Engineer"));  then you repeat for other persons

Comment: Would it be possible to create multiple enum values like joe1 joe2 sally1 sally2 etc. for each attribute? Then use something to shove those values into an arraylist of names, which can then be used to put into a map

Comment: You are right, you can do those as enum values too.  Then for converting to map, infact I think we can do it directly from enum values to map (without arraylist): Map<String, Person> personsMap = EnumSet.allOf(ListOfPersons.class).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ListOfPersons::getName, Function.identity());

Comment: how would you define the enum constructor in the enum class? would it be multiple constructors since there are different enums for each attribute, ex: joe1("joe", age, 33), joe2("joe", age, 45), joe3("joe", occupation, engineer), joe4("joe", occupation, swe) and so on for the other names

Comment: @Vaibhav answer would work using a comma delimited String for multiple age and occupation to reduce duplication

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Hashmap as well,but if you are stuck with Enum you can store them in a way like

```
public enum ListOfPersons{
Joe("Joe", "40,41","Engineer,Software Engineer"), Judy("Judy", "55,65","Judge")...etc.
//methods 
}
```

This way you would always get 3 strings as the value and then you can apply simple string processing to convert them to your data structure

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english.

How about use custom class with HashMap?

like this.

```
class Person {
    private List<Integer> ages;
    private String name;
    ...
    // getter setter..
    // equals hashcode..
}

Map<String, Person> maps = new HashMap<>();
maps.add("Joe", new Person(...));
map.get("Joe");
...
```

Why should you implement it as an enum?

Comment: Instead of having raw data in a text file, we are tasked with putting the data in an enum class and taking said data from enum class and putting it into a data structure. OOP/Enum refresher I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is what is needed, but maybe there are some helpful hints in the code below

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // load some test data
        Set<Integer> joesAges = Person.JOE.getAges();
        joesAges.add(21);
        joesAges.add(34);
        joesAges.add(43);

        Set<String> joesOccupations = Person.JOE.getOccupations();
        joesOccupations.add("Engineer");
        joesOccupations.add("Software Engineer");
        joesOccupations.add("Mechanical Engineer");

        // .... and so on for all the names in Person enum

        String searchTerm = "joe occupation"; // hardcoded search terms, it should be replaced with user's input
        String searchTermSeparator = " ";
        int indexOfSearchTermsSeparator = searchTerm.indexOf(searchTermSeparator);
        String searchName = searchTerm;
        String searchDetails = "age"; // initialze with age as default option for search, if user only types a name
        if (indexOfSearchTermsSeparator > -1) {
            searchName = searchTerm.substring(0, indexOfSearchTermsSeparator);
            searchDetails = searchTerm.substring(indexOfSearchTermsSeparator + 1);
        }
        try {
            Person person = Person.valueOf(searchName.toUpperCase());
            if ("age".equals(searchDetails)) {
                // list all ages for searched name
                String agesString = person.getAges()
                                          .stream()
                                          .map(age -> {return "" + age;})
                                          .collect(Collectors.joining( ", age: " ));

                System.out.println(searchName + " age: " + agesString);
            } else {
                // list all occupations of searched name
                String occupationsString = person.getOccupations()
                      .stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(", occupation: " ));

                System.out.println(searchName + " occupation: " + occupationsString);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unknown name");
        }
    }
}
enum Person {
    JOE(new TreeSet<Integer>(), new TreeSet<String>()),
    JANE(new TreeSet<Integer>(), new TreeSet<String>()),
    JUDY(new TreeSet<Integer>(), new TreeSet<String>())
    //.... and so on for all the names
    ;

    private Set<Integer> ages;
    private Set<String> occupations;

    Person(Set<Integer> ages, Set<String> occupations) {
        this.ages = ages;
        this.occupations = occupations;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getAges() {
        return this.ages;
    }

    public Set<String> getOccupations() {
        return this.occupations;
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.ages = new TreeSet<>();
        this.occupations = new TreeSet<>();
    }
}
```